# Nested foreach binding in knockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I want to create accordions with the help of AJAX data through knockout JS foreach binding. Each Accordion group includes a table whose data is supposed to be fetched through another AJAX call when the particular accordion is clicked with the help of knockout JS click binding.

Issue that i am facing:

First foreach binding works well without any issues and it creates the exact number of accordion groups as per the data returned. Click binding on accordion also works well and gets correct data through AJAX call.

However,  the moment i add the second for each binding everything falls apart. Even the years foreach binding stops rendering after the first accordion group.

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: years">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion"
               data-toggle="collapse" href="" data-bind="click: $parent.get_statement, attr: { href: '#' + year0,}, text: year2 + ' ' + year0 + ' - ' + year1">Financial Year
                2014-15</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="" data-bind="attr: {id: year0}">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column A</th>
                        <th>Column B</th>
                        <th>Column C</th>
                        <th>Column D</th>
                        <th>Column E</th>
                        <th>Column F</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: statements">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: A">cell is row 0, column 0</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: B">cell is row 0, column 1</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: C">cell is row 0, column 2</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: D">cell is row 0, column 3</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: E">cell is row 0, column 4</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: F">cell is row 0, column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
this.years = ko.observableArray();
this.statements = ko.observableArray();

$.ajax({
            url: "site_api/user_data.php",
            type: "get",
            data: {data_type: getParam("id"), request_type: "account_statement_years", data_value: 0},
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                self.years(data);
            }
        });

        this.get_statement = function() {
            var c = self.years.indexOf(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: "site_api/user_data.php",
                type: "get",
                data: {data_type: getParam("id"), request_type: "account_statement_data", data_value: self.years()[c].year0},
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                    self.statements(data);
                }
            });
        };
```

Sample Data:

```
Years: [{year0: 2015, year2:16, year3: ABC},{year0: 2014, year2:15, year3: DEF},{year0: 2013, year2:14, year3: GHI}]
```

Statements:

```
[{"A":"AQA", "B":"BQB", "C":"CQC", "D":"DQD", "E":"EQE", "F":"FQF"},
{"A":"AQA", "B":"BQB", "C":"CQC", "D":"DQD", "E":"EQE", "F":"FQF"},
{"A":"AQA", "B":"BQB", "C":"CQC", "D":"DQD", "E":"EQE", "F":"FQF"}]
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed some typos, everything looks alright, but your model doesn't make sense.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.years = ko.observableArray();
    self.statements = ko.observableArray();

    this.years([
        {year0: 2015, year2:16, year3: 'ABC'},
        {year0: 2014, year2:15, year3: 'DEF'},
        {year0: 2013, year2:14, year3: 'GHI'}
    ]);


    self.get_statement = function() {
         //your ajax here 
        self.statements([
            {"A":"AQA", "B":"BQB", "C":"CQC", "D":"DQD", "E":"EQE", "F":"FQF"},
            {"A":"AQA", "B":"BQB", "C":"CQC", "D":"DQD", "E":"EQE", "F":"FQF"},
            {"A":"AQA", "B":"BQB", "C":"CQC", "D":"DQD", "E":"EQE", "F":"FQF"}
        ]);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Html:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: years">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion"
               data-toggle="collapse" href="" data-bind="click: $parent.get_statement, attr: { href: '#' + year0,}, text: year2 + ' ' + year0">Financial Year
                2014-15</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="" data-bind="attr: {id: year0}">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column A</th>
                        <th>Column B</th>
                        <th>Column C</th>
                        <th>Column D</th>
                        <th>Column E</th>
                        <th>Column F</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.statements">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: A">cell is row 0, column 0</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: B">cell is row 0, column 1</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: C">cell is row 0, column 2</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: D">cell is row 0, column 3</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: E">cell is row 0, column 4</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: F">cell is row 0, column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/n7nqp5uv/1/

I recommend you to use a view-model like this:

```
function Year(name, statements) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = name;
   self.statements = ko.observableArray(statements);
};

funtion ViewModel() {
  //...
  self.years = ko.observableArray();
  //load the years like this (arrayOfYears returned from ajax):
  //self.years(ko.utils.arrayMap(arrayOfYears, function (y) {
  //    return new Year(y.name, []);
  //};

  //function to load the year's statements
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: years">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion"
               data-toggle="collapse" href="" data-bind="click: $root.yourFunctionToLoadTheStatements, attr: { href: '#' + year0,}, text: year2 + ' ' + year0">Financial Year
                2014-15</a>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="" data-bind="attr: {id: year0}">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Column A</th>
                        <th>Column B</th>
                        <th>Column C</th>
                        <th>Column D</th>
                        <th>Column E</th>
                        <th>Column F</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: statements">
                    <tr>
                        <td data-bind="text: A">cell is row 0, column 0</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: B">cell is row 0, column 1</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: C">cell is row 0, column 2</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: D">cell is row 0, column 3</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: E">cell is row 0, column 4</td>
                        <td data-bind="text: F">cell is row 0, column 5</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to change the style of <tr> depending upon the value of A. How it can be implemented ?

Comment: <tr data-bind="css: { 'yourClass': A == 'Value' }''>

Comment: or <tr data-bind=" style: ... "> http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

Comment: I tried following: <tr data-bind="css: { danger: A() > 0}"> but it keeps giving me error Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "css: function (){return { danger:A() > 0} }"
Message: with_employee is not a function

Comment: Are you sure that A is a function? What if you try  <tr data-bind="css: { danger: A > 0}">

Comment: A is the name of the column from database. You see in my question i have used AJAX to query database and return a array which is assigned to statements observableArray on which a for each loop runs. One of the value in that obsrvableArray is "A".

Comment: Have you tried  this  <tr data-bind="css: { danger: A > 0}"> ? without parentheses